# Can't get picture out of NAS form webpage who runs on iis

Tags: html, iis, storage, nas

I'm trying to search a picture that is stored in a NAS (network attached storage) from a html page.

code:
'image.setAttribute('src', '/NASFolder.lnk/' + orderNummer + 'a.jpg');'

error:
'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Y:/NASFolder/15134819b.jpg'

Comment: First please make sure the path of your file is correct, is this error only occurred on iis? can it work locally?

Comment: Also tried it on the appache server, the same problem appeared. Locally it works, but we have to access the site on several computers. We currently own an iis server so we use this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure a virtual directory for iis to solve this problem.

1. Open the Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager;
2. Right-click the site you want to add a virtual directory, and select the "Add a virtual directory" option from the pop-up menu;
3. Enter the name of the virtual directory in the Alias text box of the pop-up dialog, and then click the button to the right of the Physical Path;
4. Select the target folder of the virtual directory in the pop-up browsing folder dialog box, and then click "OK" button;

Comment: thank you for your comment, I tried this but can't see the directory (Y), the directory of my NAS. I also tried to select a link to that folder but it is not listed either.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Is it the same problem?

Comment: I have already tried this on different browsers but still the same error!

Comment: What authentication are you using? Anonymous authentication or something else? You can try using windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

My path need to look like this:

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZpiu.png)
[Path to create virtual directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjDbY.png)

then I see my virtual directory under the website.